# API Controller with custom action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to have a custom action for my api controller like api/{controller}/{action}/{id}

This is my config

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultMethodApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiByAction",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "Browse", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

This hit the default route /api/dropzone/1
But i try to hit /api/dropzone/browse/1 by the "ApiByAction" configuration, but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 6):

The order of your route definitions is important, make sure you respect it, because they are evaluated in the same order in which you declared them:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiByAction",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { action = @"^(?!\d)[a-z0-9]+$" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultMethodApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Also notice that you might need to specify a constraint for the `{action}` token in the first route definition.

Comment: Sorry, this brokes the default route. The /api/{action}/{id} doesnt work.

Comment: You are right. You will have to specify a constraint for the `{action}` token in your first route definition. I have updated my answer to illustrate that. Here the action name cannot start with a number and can contain letters or numbers only and it has at least one character length.